# Can't load HTML from asset folder Android Studio

Tags: android, html, xml

I already searched for different problems, and tried different solutions but nothing worked.

here's my code so far in calling the html file:

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface= new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

PC address: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\SWEEPx\app\src\main\asset

Here's the output:

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to move to another folder.
WebView.loadUrl("file:///Android_res/raw/test.HTML");//from raw folder
WebView.loadUrl("file:///Android_asset/test.HTML");//from asset folder

Comment: should i create the raw folder inside res?

Answer (score 1):

Try to setting [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccess(boolean)) for your webview:

```
public void setAllowFileAccess (boolean allow)
```

Enables or disables file access within WebView. File access is enabled by default. Note that this enables or disables file system access only. Assets and resources are still accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.

You may also look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)), hope it help.